# Taking data from image sensor display on MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, rgb, sensors

So my problem in a very general way, MATLAB keep showing only white image, sometimes one pixel blue/ red/ pink.

In detail: i’m using PSoC microcontroller, data are taken from an image sensor (OV7620)  as RGB422 (Bayer-Pattern). Then they are sent to MATLAB using UART.

Inside MATLAB, I take the data (in sequence of BGRG) and then sort them out as redChannel, greenChannel (take the average of the two greens), and blueChannel.

Then I use the function rgbImage = cat(3,redChannel, greenChannel, blueChannel) to combine the red, green, and blue.

After using imshow(rgbImage) I get the result that was described earlier.

What can be wrong from the process?

EDIT (Example as requested):

```
Data = query (obj, ‘*IDN?’); % Receive data from the uC as BGRG for example 65 45 76 60%
%Now the data will be put into blueChannel(BC), GC, RC%
blueChannel = Data(1) % this is blue
greenChannel =( Data(2) + Data(4) ) /2 %Take the AVG of green%
redChannel=Data(3) % This is red
%Now combing those three will only give me 1 pixel
rgbImage = cat(3,redChannel, greenChannel, redChannel);
imshow(rgbImage); %here the results is white picture regardless the rgb values sometimes I get like a single pixel between them blue/red/pink like a random color
```

Comment: please give a more concrete example. You can e.g. use 
`cam=webcam; testimage=cam.snapshot; clear cam;` to illustrate an example image. Taken from the webcam

Comment: I added an example, the given code is just for a single pixel, of course inside a loop it will be for like 640x480 pixels

Comment: The line `blueChannel = Data(1)` and the others look to create scalars. What are their sizes? What is the size of `Data`?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 for testing purposes, my bluechannel is 1 column and 200 rows. But the original must be 640x480. The size of the data for each cell is 8bits (0-255 range)

Comment: @JijiGaming But what is the size of `Data(1)`? It looks like a scalar. If you want `blueChannel` to be a row vector, shouldn't it be `Data(1,:)`?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 you’re totally right, I do that in my own code, I just gave here an example for 1 pixel